# Q: Edit New Password PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forgot-password

Somebody help me with my code. I create a edit password page containing the Current Password, New Password and Confirm Password. Here's my code:

edit_password.php

```
<form action="editpassword_process.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr class="form-group has-feedback has-success">
        <td><h4>Current Password</h4></td>
        <td><div class="control-group input-lg"><input type="password" placeholder="" passfield="true" id="currentpassword" name="currentpassword"></div></td> <!-- class="input-sm" required -->
        <td><span id="messagebox"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h4>New Password</h4></td>
        <td><div class="control-group input-lg"><input type="password" placeholder="" passfield="true" id="newpassword1" name="newpassword1"></div></td> <!-- required class="input-sm" -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h4>Confirm Password</h4></td>
        <td><div class="control-group input-lg"><input type="password" placeholder="" passfield="true" id="newpassword2" name="newpassword2" onKeyUp="checkPass(); return false;"></div></td> <!-- required class="input-sm" -->
        <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>
    </tr>
</table>
    <button class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here's my code of editpassword_process.php

```
<?php

include('connection.php');

$currentpw = $_POST['currentpassword'];
$newpw = $_POST['newpassword1'];
$confirmnewpw = $_POST['newpassword2'];

$res = mysql_query("SELECT user_password FROM `tbl_userlist` WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'");

if($currentpw != mysql_result($res, 0)){
    echo "You entered an incorrect password";
}

if($newpw = $confirmnewpw){
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_userlist SET user_password = '$newpw' WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'");
}

if($sql){
    echo "You have successfully changed your password";
}
else{
    echo "The new password and confirm pasword fields must be the same";
}

?>
```

When i click the submit it appears an alert that shows Validated OK but my database didn't update.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have an sql injection vulnerability  that is a much bigger problem.

Comment: Also you appear to be storing plain text passwords which is also a very big security flaw.

Comment: Most people stopped using `mysql` commands in favour of `mysqli` or `pdo` 7 years ago. Your script doesn't stop execution if the password is incorrect. You're assigning a variable, instead of comparing it (`=` vs `==`). You are storing the password in plain text (a BIG no-no). https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code, but I'll start with why your user password isn't updating. You haven't started a session anywhere in your code. Anywhere you use sessions, you need to start them with:

```
session_start();
```

<sup>*This should be the very first thing you do after your opening `<?php` tag.*</sup>

You're assigning(`=`) and not comparing (`==`) in a lot of your `if(){..` comparison blocks, these will evaluate to `TRUE`, running the condition.

Now on to the bad, you're using a deprecated library. All `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and removed as of PHP7. It's best to get ahead of the curve-ball by learning either of these 2 libraries:

- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)
- [MySQLi Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)

Either of them will mitigate any SQL Injections you'd come across with your currently **vulnerable** code. Not to mention the fact that you're storing passwords in plain text. Imagine the implications **when** (*not* ***if***) your database is hacked, I hope this isn't a production environment.

PHP makes it super simple to hash a password, just check out:

- [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
- [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

They'll sort out your password hashing.

---

To simplify what you're doing, this would be a PDO example along with hashing of your passwords to show you how simple it is to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connection.php');

$currentpw = $_POST['currentpassword'];
$newpw = $_POST['newpassword1'];
$confirmnewpw = $_POST['newpassword2'];

// start your PDO object
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE', 'username','password');
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT user_password FROM `tbl_userlist` WHERE userid = :userid");
$statement->execute(array(':userid' => $_SESSION['userid']));
// check if we have a row
if ($statement->rowCount() > 0) {
    $data = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $current_password_hash = $data['user_password'];
    // check current password is correct.
    if (!password_verify($currentpw, $current_password_hash)) {
        // wrong "current" password.
        die("You entered an incorrect password");
    }
    // check that both passwords match.
    if (trim($confirmnewpw) !== trim($newpw)) {
        // new passwords dont match
        die("The new password and confirm pasword fields must be the same");
    }
    // can only get here if passwords match.
    // so hash the new password and store in the database.
    $newpwhash = password_hash(trim($confirmnewpw), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 11));
    // now lets update table to add new password hash.
    $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE tbl_userlist SET user_password = :newpwhash WHERE userid = :userid");
    if($update->execute(array(':newpwhash' => $newpwhash, ':userid' => $_SESSION['userid']))) {
        // password updated successfully.
        die("You have successfully changed your password");
    } else {
        // failed to update, check logs to ammend.
        die('Failed to update password.');
    }
} else {
    // wrong "current" password.
    die("No password found for you...");
}
```

Needless to say, this will mean you'll have to change your login process too, but it's simple. All you'll need to do is fetch the password and harness `password_verify()`, and voila, you're sorted.

<sup>*(Not to mention, a ton more secure.)*</sup>

Comment: @pvegetah My pleasure mate. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Change following things

```
    <?php
session_start(); // Start session as you are using it
include('connection.php');

$currentpw = $_POST['currentpassword'];
$newpw = $_POST['newpassword1'];
$confirmnewpw = $_POST['newpassword2'];

$res = mysql_query("SELECT user_password FROM `tbl_userlist` WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'");

if($currentpw != mysql_result($res, 0)){
    echo "You entered an incorrect password";
}

if($newpw = $confirmnewpw){ // Compare using == or ===
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_userlist SET user_password = '$newpw' WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'");
// mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_userlist SET user_password = '$newpw' WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'", $connectionVar);
}

if($sql){ // Here You have not executed the query now use $connection->query($sql)
// OR mysql_query($connection,$sql); any other
    echo "You have successfully changed your password";
}
else{
    echo "The new password and confirm password fields must be the same";
} ?>
```

Comment: if you have used connection var then try to echo error like this `echo mysqli_error($con);` check for mysql it is for mysqli connection. After checking error someone will be able to help you. so post your error

Comment: also correct that `mysql_query($connectionVariable, $sqlQuery);`

Answer (score 0):

when you running this code :

```
"UPDATE tbl_userlist SET user_password = '$newpw' WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'"
```

that's mean you update tbl_userlist with criteria userid from session. value from session can be used if you start the session using code `session_start();`